# How to mongoexport csv one particular key from all the instances of an array as one field?

Tags: mongodb, csv, export-to-csv, mongoexport

I have a MongoDB collection as follows:

```json
{
 "keya" : "vala",
 "keyb" : "valb",
 "keyc" : [
   {"keyd1" : "valdoc1_a1", "keyd2" : "valdoc1_a2", "keyd3" : "valdoc1_a3"},
   {"keyd1" : "valdoc1_b1", "keyd2" : "valdoc1_b2", "keyd3" : "valdoc3_b3"}
 ]
}
```

Each document in the collection has the form above. The *keyc* array has different number of instances (values) in each document. I want to export only the *keyd1* value for all the instances of the array to a csv file. Example of output:
[For 4 records in the collection this is the csv output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7OMX.jpg)

I have tried two different calls to mongoexport; the first one:

```
mongoexport \
--host localhost \
--db dbs \
--collection col \
--type=csv \
--fields keyc \
--out r.csv
```

This exports all the key value pairs for all the instances of array.

The second try:

```
mongoexport \
--host localhost \
--db dbs \
--collection col \
--type=csv \
--fields keyc.0.keyd1 \
--out r.csv
```

This exports only the 1st key (i.e. valdoc1_a1) in 1st array instance.

What can be done to export only one specific key-value pair(keyd1) for each array instance in every document (i.e. both valdoc1_a1 and valdoc1_b1)?

Comment: Hi Kunal - can you give us an example of the output you're trying to get? I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I want to output all the values for keyd1 only. Not for any specific array instance (like keyc[0] or keyc[1]) but for all the instances of keyc, I want to output keyd1 values. I do not want keyd2 or keyd3 values either. Suppose I have 4 records in the collection, so I want 4 rows in the csv and each row should contain all the keyd1 values in that document. I hope you get what I want.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to include an example? That would be best.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I have attached an image file for the output example. This should give more clarity, I hope.